# Phone Number Validation In Generic Way...?

Tags: java

I have a requirement to validate the phone number. The validation should be validate any kind of phone number weather its an Indian number or US number or other country number. My validation should validate these numbers. So how can I starts with this...?

I have a question how the telecommunication service providers will validated the phone numbers...?

Can you please provide some suggestions.

Thanks,
Amar.

Comment: What exactly is ur requirement ?? Validate that only numbers are entered or to validate that the phone number is a valid number ??

Comment: You need the validation rules for each country you have to support and then some way of determining which rule to apply

Comment: @ShuhailKadavath I think  OP wants to validate whether a phone number is a valid one or not.

Comment: This topic is by far to broad. What you want to validate? That a number is in the correct format, or a number actually exists?
There is a lot of differences in number format for each country, and there is also special numbers in most countries (like emergency numbers, service numbers for government) which do not fullfil standard requirements (e.g. to length).

Comment: Validate to what extent? Checking for a correct number of digits is one thing, checking if the telephone company has connected the line is another.

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: +1 I found a superb library bcz of this question.

Comment: @Chandra Sekhar This library e.g. does not recognize special numbers (emergency and service numbers). It basically just validates if the number is valid according to a few standards, better than nothing, but not complete.

Comment: @Matthias Yeah u r right. Its validating properly for numbers except emmergency and value added service numbers.

Comment: @Matthias Using ShortNumberUtil we can validate the emergency numbers also. Unfortunately its not included in Demo.

Comment: @Matthias I need both validation and as well as checking if the telephone company has connected the line or not. I need both validations. Can you tell me is there any approach to solve this...

Please help me on this I stuck over here...

Comment: @Joni I need both validation and as well as checking if the telephone company has connected the line or not. I need both validations. Can you tell me is there any approach to solve this... Please help me on this I stuck over here...

Comment: For checking if a phone number is connected there is no easy way as long as you cannot call / access the phone (e.g. by sending a SMS to the phone).
If you just need to make sure that a entered phone number is in a valid format and belongs to a certain user, then there are quite a few options (most involving sending a SMS with a one time code and providing a web-page, input-field for entereing the one time code for the user).

Comment: So we need to maintain the all the codes and the related phone numbers in the database right @Matthias ...?

Comment: If you want to validate with SMS you should make sure the code is only valid for a short time (maybe 5 or 10 minutes), so you are quite confident that the owner of the phone is sending the code to you, not somebody else who finds the SMS a few hours / days later.
So you basically could store phone number and code in memory, and just change the status of the phone number to validated in the database, once validation was done successful.

Comment: Thanx @Matthias. And one more help Matthias. Is there any standard API to achieve this ...?

Comment: I am not aware of any international standard here. I implemented sms phone number validation once in Germany using a local provider. Basically you would need a telecommunications provider that routes sms reliably to the mobile phones of all countries interesting for your use case. Maybe you should rephrase your question accordingly and see if anybody else can be of assistance for this topic.
Once your question is so specific, you probably find a lot of people willing to answer your question.

Comment: Ok @Matthias Thanq you very much. I will raise one more question on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's Phone number library may help you. This is used by Google in Android framework. [see this.](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/)